# Edit particular Excel sheet by inserting values into the Excel with predefined templates in Java

Tags: java, excel

I want to edit an Excel sheet with some pre designed templates containing pie charts and graphs using java.

All I have to do is read some values from a different raw data Excel and insert the values into some specific cell in the Excel with the template. Reading values is done from external data sheet, I tried a lot to write the data into the Excel with the template.

Comment: I was actually doing a similar thing with charts. what I did is I created a chart first selecting the data from a table. then using java i just updated the table using `apachepoi` and the chart updates automatically

Comment: Have you looked into http://poi.apache.org/
A library to read and write excel files.

Comment: yes, but I found that most of the code clears the existing worksheet and insert new.But I need the template of the excel to be the same,and over that I need to insert the values.

Comment: This is a kind of reporting tool am working with.I have to generate the report using the raw data every since.And therefore the excel template should be unaltered and the data should be over-written on that.

Comment: that is what i did I created a web page with a download option accordin to the input. the output template remained the same.

Comment: no it is possible to open the existing sheet and just update specific values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code is

```
 FileInputStream fileIn =null;
 FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
 final Workbook wb; 

      fileIn =new FileInputStream("d:\\excelfiles\\Report.xlsm");
      wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fileIn); //open existing file
      final Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Report");//open the existing sheet use wb.createSheet() to create a new one
      row = sheet.getRow(0/*row number*/);
      if (row == null)//if row not exists
          row = sheet.createRow(0);
      cellp = row.getCell(4);
      if (cellp == null)
         cellp = row.createCell(0);
```

**note** I removed all the exception handling. look more in the api